# Surface view as a bitmap in android

Tags: android, surfaceview, cocos2d-android

I'm using cocos2d.

Now I've added some images in the layer, and played around a bit.

I'm trying to save the whole screen as image file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that cocos2d-android also has a CCRenderTexture class with the saveBuffer method. In that case [have a look at my CCRenderTexture demo program and blog post](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/) for cocos2d-iphone which gives you an example for how to create a screenshot using CCRenderTexture and saveBuffer. The same principle should be applicable to cocos2d-android.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to capture the content of a SurfaceView is if you are rendering into it using OpenGL. You can use glReadPixels() to grab the content of the surface. If you are drawing onto the SurfaceView using a Canvas, you can simply create a Bitmap, create a new Canvas for that Bitmap and execute your drawing code with the new Canvas.

Comment: see this link. I have explained my problem here in more detail.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531481/cocos-2d-screen-shot-is-black-in-android