# Taking screenshot of surfaceView giving black screen

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a surfaceView for recording. However, I also need to capture the image when button click.Is it possible to get the image from the current surface view with background content?
I tried many google suggested solutions but not giving me a proper result.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/8470928/3836513

Comment: you can also use horizonsdk (able to capture photo while video recording)